# Lakehouse architecture using Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm attempting to create a data platform implementing a lakehouse architecture using Azure Synapse. The data to be processed arrives as CDC tables in an Azure Storage Account in the form of CSV-files. It will later be displayed in Power BI once some pruning and light data modelling has been performed on the data.

The data volume is low and will continue to be so - especially if the data platform only performs incremental loads. Therefore, I want to avoid creating dedicated spark or SQL pools and only use the built in serverless sql pool to keep the costs down.
Once the data has been pruned and modelled, I want it to be stored as parquet or delta tables in the Storage Account that already exists.

This is the first time I do anything with Azure Synapse, so it came as a shock to me that the External Tables that I can create using the serverless SQL pool does not support DML operations. This means that once I read data from the source, modify it and save it as an external table I cannot append or modify new rows, making incremental loads impossible.

What is my best alternative for implementing this architecture? Do I have to create dedicated pools of some sort? Maybe I can do what I want to but I dont know how? Maybe it would be cheaper to just create a serverless Azure SQL database and store data there once it has been processed? I want my solution to use the resources that already exists (Storage Account and Synapse) be as cheap as possible while still being able to scale up in the future if necessary.

Comment: You can create serverless pool Views over your storage and access them from Power BI. For performance reasons, I would avoid DirectQuery. Also, make sure the Views use the WITH clause to define a proper schema, especially for any character data types.

Comment: Thank you @JoelCochran, but only using views does not fulfil my requirements. I need to be able to modify the source data and store it again before it is pushed to Power BI. I need this layer of tables between the raw data and visualisation to implement surrogate keys, slowly changing dimensions and other logic.